# Regular expression to clean Amazon links

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to clean up Amazon URLs, but I can't remove the middle part.

From the example attached, I want the "Group 2" to disappear in the final result. Is it possible?

I use this regular expression: `^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)([^\/]+)(\s?.*)(/[dg]p/)([^/]+)`

And I would a result like this:

```
https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Melange-Performance-T-Shirt-Charcoal/dp/B07P4LVZNL/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_2?dchild=1&keywords=Adidas+M%C3%A8lange+Tech+T-Shirt+A372&qid=1579685244&sr=8-2-fkmr1 --> https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07P4LVZNL

https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Originals-Solid-Melange-Purple/dp/B07DXPN7TK/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_1?dchild=1&keywords=Adidas+M%C3%A8lange+Tech+T-Shirt+A372&qid=1579685244&sr=8-1-fkmr2 --> https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DXPN7TK

https://www.amazon.es/gp/B07R23QGH6/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_2?dchild=1&keywords=Adidas+M%C3%A8lange+Tech+T-Shirt+A372&qid=1579685244&sr=8-2-fkmr2 --> https://www.amazon.com/gp/B07R23QGH6

https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07R23QGH6/ --> https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07R23QGH6/
```

https://regex101.com/r/AFGk96/1

Comment: Maybe it's ok only make the capture group anonym? `^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)([^\/]+)(?:.*)(/[dg]p/)([^/]+)`

Comment: Just place your substitutions accordingly like [this](https://regex101.com/r/AFGk96/2)

Comment: Oh! Yes @Liju, this is perfect.

Comment: Thanks @TheSlater!!

Comment: Finally, I used the @Liju 's solution with a little modification. Thanks a lot!

https://regex101.com/r/AFGk96/3

Answer (score 1):

You're over-escaping. Slashes have no meaning in regular expressions, there is no requirement to escape them:

```
^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)([^\/]+)(\s?.*)(/[dg]p/)([^/]+)
```

could be (with a few other simplifications)

```
^(?:https?://)?(www[^/]+).*?(/[dg]p/[^/]+)
```

When we add `.*` to the end to match the tail of the string, we end up with something that works:

```
import re

amazon_url_pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:https?://)?(www[^/]+).*?(/[dg]p/[^/]+).*')

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/adidas-Melange-Performance-T-Shirt-Charcoal/dp/B07P4LVZNL/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_2?dchild=1&keywords=Adidas+M%C3%A8lange+Tech+T-Shirt+A372&qid=1579685244&sr=8-2-fkmr1'
result = amazon_url_pattern.sub(r'\1\2/', url)

print(result)
```

prints

```
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07P4LVZNL/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: I've found another use case for URLs ... when they have "/ product" in between, I can't find it with the regex.

https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07R23QGH6/

Comment: @user13383010 I'm sure you can figure that one out on your own. :)